# PyCharm remote debugging

Tags: python, remote-debugging, pycharm

I have remote Ubuntu server, and I'm trying set up remote debugging.
Configured as shown [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2010/12/python-remote-debug-with-pycharm/).

```
import sys
import pydevd
sys.path.append('/root/home/scripts/pycharm-debug.egg')
pydevd.settrace('my_remote_server_IP', port=51234,
stdoutToServer=True, stderrToServer=True)
```

I also connect remote host for synchronizing and uploading my python scripts to remote server. (Tools -> Deployment -> ...)

When I start debugging:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Projects/python/demo.py
Could not connect to xx.xx.xx.166: 51234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 428, in StartClient
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10061] ����������� �� �����������,

Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument of `pydevd.settrace` function should be the host, where PyCharm is installed. Not remote server.
Also in most cases if you want to run and debug your code remotely it is more convenient to use [remote interpreter feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/webhelp/configuring-remote-python-interpreters.html).

Comment: Ok. But also dont work:                                          Could not connect to xx.xx.22.135: 51234
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 2.7.1\helpers\pydev\pydevd_comm.py", line 428, in StartClient
    s.connect((host, port))
  File "C:\Python27\Lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 10060]

Comment: Remote Interpreter via SSH works well. But when I editing code in pycharm - python.exe in my host machine breaks down. http://pastexen.com/i/jgJQZ6ne.png

Comment: If your initial problem is solved, please accept an answer to make it usefull for others. Local intepreter is executed to perform PEP-8 checks, you can disable it in Settings | Inspections -> PEP 8 Code style violations. Anyway if your local python is crashed then it is broken and worth to be reinstalled. Or it works normally?

Comment: If I used local python - it works normally, when I change on remote python - local python is crashed.I disable PEP 8 Code style violations, and my problem solved. Thx!

Comment: That's a weird problem. Could you please create an issue about that in our tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY and attach there a log (Help | Show log in Explorer).

Comment: As a workaround I could propose to remove this local interpreter form interpreters list - that should help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem by changing the port.